# How to get list of available youtube subtitles from youtube-dl python api alongside other video informations

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I have been using youtube-dl python Api for getting information about videos on youtube. here is part of my code I used to retrieve video information.

```
ydl_opts = {'simulate' : True, 'print_json': True, 'extract_flat': True}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts);
meta = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuOBzWF0Aws');
```

here `meta` contains video information in json format. 
Now I want to get list of available video subtitles alongside video information I tried with the following code:

```
ydl_opts = {'simulate' : True, 'print_json': True, 'extract_flat': True, 'listsubtitles': True}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts);
meta = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuOBzWF0Aws');
```

but this code would just print the available subtitles in stdout and `meta` is empty.
now I have two problems.
1- is there a way to get list of available subtitles in array or json format? 
2- how to get list of subtitles alongside video information in **one request**?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the following configuration returns video info along with subtitles and automatic captions lists:

```
ydl_opts = {"writesubtitles": True, "writeautomaticsub": True}
```